# List or Select List keeps returning Object Reference Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core, selectlistitem

My App is using Asp.Net Core. EF Core. I'm using a ViewModel, Not the EF Model,  and a Repository Pattern. My View Model I created myself. It's not wired up to EF or anything. Maybe that's where I'm going wrong?

Edit New ViewModel:

```
public partial class CommodityViewModel
{
    public CommodityViewModel()
    {

    }
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CommoditiesItems { get; set; }


    public Guid Oid { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: New Interface
Here is my interface:

```
    public interface ICommodityRepository
{

    IEnumerable<CommodityViewModel> GetCommodities();

}
```

My question on my interface is can I use IEnumerable for a List or Select List?

Edit New Repository:

```
public class CommodityRepository : ICommodityRepository
{    
    private readonly CommodityViewModel _context;


    public CommodityRepository(CommodityViewModel context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<CommodityViewModel> GetCommodities()
    {
        return _context.CommoditiesList.ToList();
    }



 }
```

Here is my controller:

```
    public class CommoditiesController : Controller
{
     private readonly ICommodityRepository _commoditiyRepository;

    public CommoditiesController(ICommodityRepository commodityRepository)
    {

        _commoditiyRepository = commodityRepository;
    }
    public IActionResult CommoditiesList()
    {

        return View(_commoditiyRepository.GetCommodities());

    }


}
```

And my View which I am using the Layout to display the drop down because I want it accessible from every page. (I know I should put it in a partial view. I just want to get it working first.):

```html
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
                    <li>
                        <select asp-for="Code" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.CommoditiesList,"Code","Description"))">
                            <option>Please select one</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Here is the error I cannot get past:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
MoveNext in _Layout.cshtml, line 134

```html
  <!-- Here: Line 134--><select asp-for="Code" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.CommoditiesList,"Code","Description"))">
                            <option>Please select one</option>
                        </select>
```

I really don't know where I'm going wrong. I have instantiated a new list in the repository method.  I've even instantiated a new List in the ViewModel. Can some point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Does your Layout has a Model ? Looks like the code is using `Model.Commodities`

Answer (score 0):

SelectListItem is a UI concern so your repository should not return that, it should return IEnumerable or List and you transform that into a IEnumerable or List of SelectListItem in the controller.

I'm doing something similar in my project with a list of TimeZones. The ViewModel has a property for IEnumerable of SelectListItem, my data is coming from a read only collection. my code is like this:

```
model.TimeZoneId = selectedSite.TimeZoneId;
model.AllTimeZones = tzHelper.GetTimeZoneList().Select(x =>
                   new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Text = x,
                       Value = x,
                       Selected = model.TimeZoneId == x
                   });
```

and my razor view is like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TimeZoneId" class="col-md-2 control-label">@sr["Time Zone"]</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="TimeZoneId"
                    asp-items="Model.AllTimeZones" class="form-control"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="TimeZoneId" class="text-danger"></span> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I instantiate the new SelectListItem {Selected = model.code} :Error: Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type string or myViewModel.